# MVC 4 .net send generic object (not necessarily json)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an mvc 4 application.
In one of the post actions I would like to have a parameter of type 'object'.
It should be able to accept from the client an number, a string, and also generic json.

I tried implementing it with the following model binder:

```
public class ObjectModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = js.Deserialize<object>((string)value.ConvertTo(typeof(string)));
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

In the client I use jquery ajax to post the data, and also if the value is a javascript object I use JSON.stringify.

When I send a json or an int it works, but if I try sending a string it will throws an exception - "Invalid JSON primitive: THE_STRING_VALUE"

Should I use something else?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what string are you sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that JSON *is* a string, so you need to be able to differentiate between strings that are JSON and those that aren't.  Try something like this instead:

```
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            int n;
            string s = (string)value.ConvertTo(typeof(string));
            if (s.StartsWith("{") || s.StartsWith("["))
            {
                var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var result = js.Deserialize<object>(s);
                return result;
            }
            else if (int.TryParse(s, out n))
            {
                return n;
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
```